# Check if user has permission to access module in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I using joomla 2.5. I have made a custom module. I need to run some codes in component if that user had permission to access the module. 
Is there a function to check that if the user has permission access to the module.

Comment: Do you have any ACL configuration for your module? What kind of access are we talking about?

Comment: Suppose, I created a custom viewing access level('XYZ') from user manager.  'XYZ' has set to access to public group only. In module setting page, I have set 'XYZ' in access label. All i am looking for is , a method/function to check if a user has access to the module(If user has access return 1 else return false/empty).